# Problems with a Web-Scrapping in Python "AttributeError: 'WebDriver'"

Tags: python, html, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

I have the following problem when webscraping a shein page.

In general the problem is with attributes and in relation to - AttributeError: 'WebDriver' object has no attribute 'find_elements_by_xpath' -

If any of you have faced this problem, I would like to know your suggestions for a solution.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
import pandas as pd

# Create a new instance of the Firefox driver
driver = webdriver.Firefox()

# Navigate to the Shein website
driver.get("https://www.shein.com.mx/style/Women-Clothing-sc-001121425.html?ici=mx_tab01navbar04&src_module=topcat&src_tab_page_id=page_select_class1686667964514&src_identifier=fc%3DWomen%60sc%3DROPA%60tc%3D0%60oc%3D0%60ps%3Dtab01navbar04%60jc%3DitemPicking_001121425&srctype=category&userpath=category-ROPA")

# Wait for the page to load
time.sleep(2)

# Close the cookie consent popup if it appears
try:
    close_button = driver.find_element_by_class_name("cookie-close-btn")
    close_button.click()
except:
    pass

# Create lists to store the extracted data
product_names = []
prices = []
urls = []

# Extract the product names, prices, and URLs from the homepage
product_elements = driver.find_elements_by_xpath(".//div[@class='product-list.j-expose__product-list.j-product-list-info.j-da-event-box']")
for product_element in product_elements:
    name_element = product_element.find_element_by_xpath(".//div[@class='S-product-item__name']")
    price_element = product_element.find_element_by_xpath(".//span[@class='normal-price-ctn__sale-prices']")
    url_element = product_element.find_element_by_xpath(".//a[@class='S-product-item__link']")
    
    name = name_element.text
    price = price_element.text
    url = url_element.get_attribute("href")
    
    product_names.append(name)
    prices.append(price)
    urls.append(url)

# Create a pandas DataFrame from the extracted data
data = {
    "Product Name": product_names,
    "Price": prices,
    "URL": urls
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Save the DataFrame to an Excel file
df.to_excel("shein_products.xlsx", index=False)

# Close the browser
driver.quit()
```

I get the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[32], line 27
     24 urls = []
     26 # Extract the product names, prices, and URLs from the homepage
---> 27 product_elements = driver.find_elements_by_xpath(".//div[@class='product-list.j-expose__product-list.j-product-list-info.j-da-event-box']")
     28 for product_element in product_elements:
     29     name_element = product_element.find_element_by_xpath(".//div[@class='S-product-item__name']")

AttributeError: 'WebDriver' object has no attribute 'find_elements_by_xpath'
```

I am hoping to be able to correctly get the price for each product identified on the Shein page.

Can you provide me with any suggestions to solve this problem?

Greetings, Alexis

Comment: Selenium has made `find_element_by_xxx` deprecated. So the new version, you have to write like shown here: https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html